# Получить scrollTop элемента на телефоне при свайпе

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, может кто-то знает как получать правильный `scrollTop` на моб. устройствах при прокрутке. Использую такой код:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(){
 var scroll =  ($(window).scrollTop() || $("body").scrollTop());
   console.log(scroll);
 }, {passive: true});
```

Этот код работает, но только если я касаюсь экрана и вожу по нему вверх-вниз пальцем, но если я например проскролю до середины станицы, а затем быстро свайпну пальцем вверх/вниз отпустив палец, то сколл(его значение) не изменится, хоть и я окажусь вверху или в самом низу станицы.
Собственно вопрос: как отслеживать `scrollTop`, когда сделали свайп и страница сама крутится без участия пользователя?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
 var scroll =  ($(window).scrollTop() || $("body").scrollTop());
   console.log(scroll);
 }, {passive: true});
```